# How to combine @media queries with @container queries?

Tags: containers, media

I am making now adaptive and responsive layout of a site. The site consists of a general container and three elements (i.e. blocks with photo and text) inside. For better adaptive and responsive properties I would like to make the general container depending on viewport - i.e. be with @media queries, and all the three blocks be compatible with changes of a general container size, using @container queries.
As you understand - changes of viewport - change the general container, which in its turn, change its inner blocks.
Is it possible? Share your experience

Reply and examples of useful code